# How to define $.get url using enablePrettyUrl=>true

Tags: ajax, yii2

Following code will do its job as intended, if `enablePrettyUrl` will be set to `false`:

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS
   $('#zip_code').change(function(){
       var zipId=$(this).val();
       $.get('index.php?r=locations/get-city-province',{zipId:zipId},function(data){
       var data=$.parseJSON(data);
       alert(data.city+" liegt in "+data.province+"! Die Id ist "+zipId);
       $('#customers-city').attr('value',data.city);
       $('#customers-province').attr('value',data.province);
   });
});

JS;
$this->registerJS($script);
?>
```

Following code won't, if `enablePrettyUrl` will be set `true`:

```
 $.get('locations/get-city-province',{zipId:zipId},function(data){
```

Here are rules of `UrlManager`:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'rules' => [
        'locations' => 'locations/index',
        'locations_create' => 'locations/create',
        'locations_delete' => 'locations/delete',
        'locations_update' => 'locations/update',
        'locations_SaveAsNew' => 'locations/save-as-new',
        'locations_pdf' => 'locations/pdf',
        'locations_view' => 'locations/view',
        // ...
    ],
],
```

Any ideas, how to code `$.get` in correct way?
Here is method of Controller:

```
public function actionGetCityProvince($zipId) {
    $location = Locations::findOne($zipId);
    echo Json::encode($location);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Url::to()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl#to()-detail) or [Url::toRoute()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl#toRoute()-detail)

```
<?php
$url = yii\helpers\Url::to(['locations/get-city-province']);
$script = <<< JS
    $('#zip_code').change(function(){
        var zipId = $(this).val();
        $.get('$url', {zipId:zipId}, function(data){
            var data = $.parseJSON(data);
            alert(data.city+" liegt in "+data.province+"! Die Id ist "+zipId);
            $('#customers-city').attr('value',data.city);
            $('#customers-province').attr('value',data.province);
        });
   });
JS;
$this->registerJS($script);
?>
```

Comment: That will still put the zipId in the query string

Comment: @Quentin. What's the problem? Question is about prettyUrl not working.

Comment: And your code will generate `locations/get-city-province?zipId=someValue` which isn't the pretty url.

Comment: @Quentin. It will work on both cases. Nothing else i found in question.

Comment: Works great! Repuatation points for ur efforts respectively solution just have been given!